# 動画データを抜き出して別の動画ファイルを保存する方法

Tags: android

Androidにて動画編集のようなことを行いたいのですが
動画の中からあるframeの画像を抜き出す方法は下記のレコードを参考に方法があることはわかりました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808815/how-to-get-the-the-single-images-of-an-mp4-movie-in-java

ただ動画の中からある区間を抜き出して別の動画ファイルを作成したいのですが、
その方法はAndroidDeveloperを見てもわかりませんでした。

GooglePlayなどでは動画トリミングアプリ等はたくさんあるので方法はあると思うのですが、
どのような方法で実装したら良いのでしょうか？
勉強のヒントとなる情報を教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android標準APIの範囲内で行う場合、`android.media`パッケージ以下のクラスが利用できます。APIレベル毎にサポート状況が大きく異なるので、利用時はバージョンに留意ください。

- [`android.media.MediaExtractor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html): メディアコンテナからの画像／音声ストリーム抽出(Extract)
- [`android.media.MediaCodec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html): 画像／音声ストリームの復号化(Decoder)・符号化(Encoder)
- [`android.media.MediaMuxer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html): 画像／音声ストリームをメディアコンテナ形式に結合（多重化; Multiplexer）

Comment: ありがとうございます。その周りを勉強します。

Comment: 実現したい機能によりますが、`android.media`以下のクラスは非常にプリミティブな機能を提供します。個人的な感想ですが、動画処理に関する知識を要しますし、クセも強いので使いこなすにはかなり難しいと思います。まずはリンク先(本家SO)にあるような、サードパーティライブラリも検討してみてください。